# xscreensaver: How do I run a script on unlock?

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, screen-lock

I'd like to run a screen if the XFCE session is locked and unlocked. Is there a way that I can intercept this and perform certain actions when the desktop is locked or unlocked?

I see that [it is possible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock) [in Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/205334/how-do-you-get-ubuntu-to-automatically-run-a-program-every-time-the-screen-is-un); but I'd like to achieve this in Xubuntu.

I can't seem to find any events triggered by `xscreensaver` when it quits...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

xscreensaver has a `-watch` option:

> **-watch**       Prints a line each time the screensaver changes state: when the screen blanks, locks, unblanks, or when the running hack is changed. This option never returns; it is intended for use by shell scripts that want to react to the screensaver in some way.<sup>1</sup>

The `UNBLANK` state is what you are looking for. The manual includes an example script using these options.

<sup>1. http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/man3.html</sup>

Comment: Is there a way to tell xfce4 to run xscreensaver in the described way and have a script listen to its output?

Comment: Found it, nevermind. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1182514