# Light Locker - Run script on screen lock/unlock

Tags: xfce, xubuntu, screen-lock

I'd like to run a script if the XFCE session is locked and unlocked. Is there a way that I can intercept this and perform certain actions when the desktop is locked or unlocked?

I have found following solutions:

for Gnome - [Run script on screen lock/unlock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock)

for `xscreensaver` - [How do I run a script on unlock?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29232/how-do-i-run-a-script-on-unlock)

But I'm using `light-locker` and no screen saver. I was trying to monitor DBUS but it doesn't seem the `light-locker` emits any signals.

One option would be to modify `xflock4` but that would help only with screen locking.

Is there any way for `light-locker`?

Comment: By "I'd like to run a screen" do you mean what in particular? Do you want to run a [screen session](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or do you only want to show some wallpaper?
You might need to customize light-locker to achieve what you want. When you monitored dbus, did you also check for any signal emitted by libdm, as that's what light-locker uses [it's a part of LightDM].

Comment: Sorry for confusion, that should've been script not screen.

Comment: Just like I thought. Seems to me you're taking the wrong approach. You should either extend the facility that calls `light-locker` (in your case [`xfce-power-manager`](http://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/tree/README) together with `upower`) so that it will not only call `xflock4` and then `light-locker` in advance, but make it more configurable. Best check some more documentation on xfce-power-manager, e.g. from LFS http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/cvs/xfce/xfce4-power-manager.html or upstream docs: http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/preferences and on systemd ...

Comment: Will try to make up an answer when I find some time to play with XFCE+light-locker myself, especially as the [systemd inhibitor thing on power management](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Power_management#Power_management_with_systemd) is pretty badly documented, from an enduser perspective. Some more links for xfce-power-manager in the meantime for you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/407287/change-xfce4-power-manager-option-from-terminal + http://askubuntu.com/questions/580109/dbus-operation-already-in-progress-error-on-return-from-suspend + https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6513

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will look into it. It's possible I missed something on the DBUS as I was not sure what to look for. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Check the systemd inhibitor link. You might want to look for events for/from `org.freedesktop.PowerManagement` or related as that is where `xfce4-power-manager` registers: http://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/tree/src/org.freedesktop.PowerManagement.Inhibit.xml
`systemd-inhibit --list` should show active inhibitors, for me under KDE e.g. currently `networkmanager` and `powerdevil` (KDE analogon to `xfce4-power-manager`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The previous answer helped me write this fragment of bash script that handles Lock and Unlock session events for the current session.  I use it to suspend browser processes when the session is locked and to resume them when it unlocks.  Tested under Debian unstable (Xfce 4.12) Enjoy!

```
session=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/$XDG_SESSION_ID
iface=org.freedesktop.login1.Session
dbus-monitor --system "type=signal,path=$session,interface=$iface" 2>/dev/null |
 while read signal stamp sender arrow dest rest; do
  case "$rest" in
    *Lock)
      echo   LOCKED at $stamp
      pause $@
;;
    *Unlock)
      echo UNLOCKED at $stamp
      resume $@
;;  #unknown Session signal received
    *)
#      echo $signal $stamp $sender $arrow $dest $rest
  esac
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 6):

Building on [Brent Roman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/211844/brent-roman)'s answer, I implemented a script using `dbus-monitor` and afterwards replaced it with `gdbus`, which has a cleaner interface and clearer output. The script is rather longish, I'll strip anything not-dbus related, to illustrate the point of running a script on screen unlock.

First a sample output from running `gdbus`, locking the screen and then unlocking it:

```
paulo@monk:~$ gdbus monitor --system --dest org.freedesktop.login1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c2
Monitoring signals on object /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c2 owned by org.freedesktop.login1
The name org.freedesktop.login1 is owned by :1.6
/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c2: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged ('org.freedesktop.login1.Session', {'Active': <false>}, @as [])
/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c2: org.freedesktop.login1.Session.Lock ()
/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c2: org.freedesktop.login1.Session.Unlock ()
/org/freedesktop/login1/session/c2: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged ('org.freedesktop.login1.Session', {'Active': <true>}, @as [])
```

So, the script skeleton:

```bsh
OBJECT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/login1/session/$XDG_SESSION_ID
BUS_NAME=org.freedesktop.login1
UNLOCK="$OBJECT_PATH: $BUS_NAME.Session.Unlock ()"
GDBUS_MONITOR="gdbus monitor --system --dest $BUS_NAME --object-path $OBJECT_PATH"
PROGNAME=$(basename "$0")
LOGFILE=~/log/$PROGNAME.log

# ...

function log {
    echo "$(date +'%F %T.%3N') [$$]" "$@"
}

# ...

function run_daemon {
    exec &>>"$LOGFILE"

    kill_running "$GDBUS_MONITOR"

    local signal
    while read -r signal; do
        log "$signal"
        if [[ $signal == "$UNLOCK" ]]; then
            check_quodlibet
        fi
    done < <(eval "exec $GDBUS_MONITOR")
}

# ...

run_daemon
```

Function `kill_running` checks if there's an instance running and kills it. If the script is autostarted with each lightdm login, we'd have potentially multiple instances running, hence the need to kill any current instances before starting.

Function `check_quodlibet` restarts [quodlibet](https://github.com/quodlibet/quodlibet) if the mounted USB device (with my music collection) has been reset (it happens randomly after resuming from suspend). I didn't think it was relevant to include it.

The `exec` when running `gdbus` is not strictly necessary, but it then avoids having an extra process, since the script will fork itself before running `gdbus`. This way, there will be only 2 processes running: the script itself and `gdbus`.

I created *~/.config/autostart/quodr.desktop* (*quodr* is the name of the script) to have the script started on each lightdm login:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=quodr
Exec=quodr
Comment=Check if quodlibet needs refresh
Icon=dialog-question-symbolic
Hidden=false
```

As a TODO to myself: I intend to investigate how to start the script as a systemd user service, D-Bus-activated.

This question with all the answers were invaluable for me to reach this solution. This problem was bugging for a very long time, I had tried many solutions, but I only got a clearer picture of what was necessary after reading what everyone wrote here. Thanks to everyone, and in particular to  [Brent Roman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/211844/brent-roman).

As a last comment, I built and installed [d-feet](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/d-feet) and [bustle](https://github.com/wjt/bustle) while I investigated this, they were really useful.

I'm running *Xubuntu 17.10*.

Comment: I've managed to run the script (which I named _quodr_) under the user instance of systemd, which allowed me to remove the restart logic and logging from the script. So, I removed `function log`, `LOGFILE` and `function kill_running`, then created _~/.config/systemd/user/quodr.service_: 

`[Unit]
Description=Refresh quodlibet after unlocking

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/paulo/bin/quodr
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=desktop.target` 

and then enabled and started it: 

`systemctl --user enable quodr.service
systemctl --user start quodr.service`

Answer (score 1):

The following runs `date` whenever you lock or unlock by light-locker. However, I don't know how to know if it is locking or unlocking.

```
dbus-monitor --system "type='signal',sender='org.freedesktop.login1',path='/org/freedesktop/login1/seat/seat0',interface='org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties',member='PropertiesChanged'" | grep --line-buffered "ActiveSession" | while read line; do date; done
```

Reference: [Launchpad bug report comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1568604/comments/86)