# How to create a daemon which would be listening to dbus and fire script on message

Tags: daemon, d-bus

I want to create a daemon, which would fire up a shell script in the background every time I unlock the screen on my ubuntu. I managed to create such script according to answer to related question: [run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock). And it works well in terminal window. But now I want to create a daemon from that and I didn't get any luck yet.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on https://askubuntu.com/questions/150790/how-do-i-run-a-script-on-a-dbus-signal

```
#!/bin/bash

interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver
member=ActiveChanged

dbus-monitor --profile "interface='$interface',member='$member'" |
while read -r line; do
    echo $line | grep ActiveChanged && your_script_goes_here
done
```

Just stick that in **/etc/init.d/monitor-for-unlock**, make it executable, and then make a soft link in rc2.d

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/monitor-for-unlock
cd /etc/rc2.d
ln -s /etc/init.d/monitor-for-unlock .
```

Comment: What exactly we are making link for in `/etc/rc2.d`? Is it autoload directory? Didn't quite worked for my ubuntu. But when added `/etc/init.d/monitor-for-unlock start` to Startup Applications worked as charm. Great response time, thanks!

Comment: Here's a conversation about rc2.d (System V init process) versus Ubuntu's upstart system: http://superuser.com/questions/151330/ubuntu-control-the-init-startup

Comment: any idea how to make it work with Unity? this is failing: `ssudo dbus-monitor --profile "interface='com.canonical.Unity',member='Locked'"` where Locked is about "com.canonical.Unity.Session.Locked", even if I use sudo...

Answer (score 0):

There's already such a daemon in the system - `upstart`, you only need to make a session job for it.

```
description "some job description"
start on desktop-unlock
script
        /path/to/your/executable
end script
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How do you create a session job for it? what is upstart? systemctl does not know any information regarding upstart.service

Comment: @brett Since it is now in maintenace mode, you might need to install it separately. It used to be Ubuntu's "event-based cron on steroids" so to say. Session jobs are single user-specific tasks. Like stuff you'd get with `crontab -e`. You create a `.conf` file with content like in this answer and put it in one of places listed here: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-job