# Execute user script as root in startup applications

Tags: permissions, users, root, startup, group

I just created a script (logscreenlock) to log lock/unlock screen events (derived from [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28183/41470)):

```
#! /bin/bash
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" | ( while true; do read X; if echo $X | grep "boolean true" &> /dev/null; then echo `date` "screen locked"; elif echo $X | grep "boolean false" &> /dev/null; then echo `date` "screen unlocked"; fi done )
```

I wanted to have a startup daemon running `logscreenlock > /var/log/screenlock.log`. Now, to write into /var/log, I need root permissions (I am a sudoer). So I would need `sudo logscreenlock > /var/log/screenlock.log`, but I have two problems with that:

1. logscreenlock is owned by my user and and I would like to keep it that way, but even after `chmod a+x logscreenlock`, I get permission denied if I try to `sudo ./logscreenlock`. I tried to `usermod -a -G <myusergroup> root`, but no luck. How can I overcome this?
2. How can I sudo in the startup applications? will it prompt me for a password right away?

---

EDIT: I found out later that the reason why I couldn't execute logscreenlock as root was that this script is in a remote filesystem where my  machine's root is not authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your username and group are *ricab*, have you tried `sudo chgrp ricab /var/log/screenlock.log` and `sudo chmod g+rw /var/log/screenlock.log`? You should then be able to read and write *screenlock.log* using your account.

Comment: That would work, but that's more of a workaround. I was looking for more general answers to the questions. "how can a user grant execute permissions to the root?" and "how can I run startup applications as root?". I will update my question to clarify that.

Comment: Well, forget the previous comment, I just found out that the reason why I couldn't execute the script as root is because the script is in a remote filesystem (where my machine's root is not authenticated)... otherwise sudo would work just fine. So I will take your workaround after all, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that you can't write to `/var/log` as a non-root user. Calling sudo is not a good solution. Don't elevate permissions unless they're actually needed for something. Write the log file in your home directory.

```
logscreenlock >~/.screenlock.log
```