# How to lock screen on lid closing using systemd?

Tags: fedora, systemd, wayland, logind, sway

I am running Sway on Fedora 26 and want my laptop to be locked when I close my screen. I changed `HandleLidSwitch` to `lock` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and ran `systemctl restart systemd-logind` after that. However, closing the lid does nothing.

The lock program I intend to use is Swaylock and I can manually call it by runnig the command `swaylock` in a terminal.

How do I make Systemd call `swaylock` when it tries to close the screen (as instructed to do in `logind.conf`)?

Comment: Normally, you can control what happens on LidSwitch through your window manager. Which window manager do you use? `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` is responsible for what happens on LidSwitch, but your window manager may 
force an inhibitor lock which overrides `logind.conf`. Oops, `logind.conf` doesn't support a script action. I think you can make one script enabling acpid daemon and writing a  `/etc/acpi/handler.sh`. For more info, consult `man logind.conf` and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=158081 and update if you find a solution. I don't have a laptop currently to test it.

Answer (score 0):

**Target**

If the `HandleLidSwitch` is set to sleep, you can create a new systemd service with sleep target, and thus your service will be executed when the sleep is called (lid closed) [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39250/120919) is an example with power target.. update that to sleep.

**Command on lock**

This [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock) explain how to run a command when the lock screen is enabled

**Screen saver**

You can use a bash to watch for screen saver if you want to trigger that when the screen saver is enabled it's explained [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1667622)