# Add a popup message on Screen Unlock on MATE

Tags: bash, linux-mint, mate-desktop

I'm looking on a way to add a popup message on screen unlock (when you leave your post unattended, your screen locks out to black and MDM and you have to input your password again to unlock) on a Linux Mint 18.1 MATE.

The question is two-fold:

- [ANSWERED] How do I detect the screen unlock event (or DBus message)?
- Where or how do I hookup the script to initiate the listener (or DBus binding)?

I now know that I can add a **zenity** popup easily from a bash script. Other than that, I'm stumped.

I have found that you can add a listener to the DBUS as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock). However, after testing the messages generated I noticed there aren't any lines with a member *ActiveChanged* involved.

I know that MATE is based on GNOME but I suspect that

```
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member=ActiveChanged"
```

does not generate messages when I lock out and into the session. I've checked changing `gnome` with `freedesktop` with the same results.

I wish there were some desktop version of a **motd** but this seems quite more complicated.

---

#### UPDATE 1

With regards to the first question, as suggested in the comments, using

`dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.mate.ScreenSaver',member=ActiveChanged"`

a screen unlock can be detected

Comment: use `org.mate.ScreenSaver`

Comment: Yes, this now works and gives me a boolean value that I can use. Now I'm just missing the hookup procedure